# MainActivity.java is not identifying any drawable or layout resource file

Tags: java, android, android-studio

My android studio project was working fine until now but when I open it now, I am not able to access any of the layout or drawable resource files.

It suddenly says

```
error: cannot find symbol
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

and the same for all the elements

This is happening only in MainActivity.java and not in any other file. This is what surprised me the most. I created a new layout resource file, a new java class with the same content but it still doesn't work

Well I seriously don't know where the problem is. If any of you know please help me

EDIT:

MainActivity.java:

```
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.view.ContextThemeWrapper;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
import androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.Voice;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupMenu;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview.TapTarget;
import com.getkeepsafe.taptargetview.TapTargetView;
import com.sayatech.dictate.ui.GotoAdapter;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_2);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTN);
        ....
```

Comment: File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

Comment: Did that didn't work though

Comment: Try to rebuild the project . build > rebuild project

Comment: @nesdi Tried rebuilding it but it still shows the same error.

Comment: which method or class is not defined?  can you access R class?

Comment: @mohammad jalili All classes and methods in Mainactivity.java are not able to access any resource file. And btw I can access R class

Comment: what about for other projects ?  are they OK ?

Comment: Yes they are fine only this one

Comment: Try disabling **VCS** .Also you may do **Build > Clean Project**

Comment: If not fixed copy all code and paste in a new project

Comment: @null_override I did that just now but I'm still getting these errors and copying all of them to a new project is impossible because it's kind of big

Comment: @Saat in that case just add your mainactivity here so that we can see

Comment: @null_override Its huge so I don't think I can put the entire thing here.

Comment: I would also say it would be helpful if you could include your code (especially including the imports). The other content that is not important in this context here can be removed from the code.

Comment: are you sure you are importing the right `R` class?

Comment: make sure your gradle file has right dependency. there might be a problem in versions. make sure their versions are correct and same as a new project gradle files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. All i did was updating Android Studio and fixed it.

Comment: I had 4.0.0 and now I updated it to 4.0.1 but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I am finally able to access the layout resource files now and that's why I am answering my own question

I changed `R.layout.activity_main to com.example.App.R.layout.activity_main` and it worked!

Please let me know if there's a better method to do it. Or am I missing any imports?

Thank you all for your support.